# C++: using typeinfo to test class inheritance

Tags: c++, rtti

I have a pointer to a polymorphic type, `p`. I also have a `type_info` for a class somewhere in the same hierarchy, `ti`.

If I just compare the `typeid(*p) == ti`, then I can test at runtime whether the pointer is pointing to a direct instance of that class.

Is there a similar way to use C++'s RTTI to test whether `*p` *inherits* from that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this in standard C++ alone. If you're using an implementation that has the [Itanium C++ ABI](http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html)<sup>1</sup>  you can do this though, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <memory>

class base {
protected:
  base() {
  }
public:
  static bool check(const std::type_info& p) {
    // Find the real type_info for single inheritance non virtual 
    const __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info* test = dynamic_cast<const __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info*>(&p);
    return test ? typeid(base) == *test->__base_type : false;
  }

  virtual ~base() {}
};

class der : public base {
};

class foo {};

int main() {
  der d;
  foo f;

  std::cout << base::check(typeid(d)) << "\n";
  std::cout << base::check(typeid(f)) << "\n";
}
```

Here this works because the type has a single, non-virtuallly inherited base. You can support more cases though with care and similar `dynamic_casts`.

Whilst this is possible under these certain circumstances I think you're solving the wrong problem though - a solution based around a `std::map` is more portable and avoids relying on implementation details like this.

<sup>1</sup> confusingly named, it's a surprisingly large compiler/architecture list, not just Itanium

Comment: I don't, alas. (I don't even have STL.) I thought this would be the answer, but couldn't find any definitive statement such. Oh, well, custom RTTI it is, then...

Comment: @DavidGiven - It might be that your implementation has a similar ABI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `dynamic_cast<>` for that purpose. If you try to cast to `Base*`, it performs a runtime check to see if your class really is derived from `Base` (or directly is a Base). In case of failure, `dynamic_cast<>` returns `nullptr`. Example :

```
struct Base {
     virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct AnotherBase {
     virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : Base {};


Base * basePtr = new Base();
Base * derivedPtr = new Derived();
AnotherBase * anotherBasePtr = new Base();

// is derivedPtr a pointer to a class derived from AnotherBase ?
AnotherBase* test2 = dynamic_cast<AnotherBase*>(derivedPtr);    // test2 == nullptr

// is basePtr a pointer to a class derived from Derived ?
Derived * test3 = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(basePtr);    // test3 == nullptr
```

Side nodes :

- if `dynamic_cast<>` is used to convert **pointers**, it returns either `nullptr` or the converted pointer.
- **BUT** when `dynamic_cast<>` is used to convert **references** it throws an **exception** in case of failure.
- The runtime check of `dynamic_cast<>` is only possible for polymorphic types. If your Base doesn't contain any virtual function (= non polymorphic), it won't be possible to safely convert a `Base*` to a `Derived*`.

Comment: Unfortunately `dynamic_cast<>` only works if I know what the class is at _compile time_. I don't know that: all I have is a `type_info` for the class. I don't actually need to cast the pointer, only determine whether the object being pointed at inherits from the class for which I have the `type_info`.

Comment: @DavidGiven I misunderstood your question. So no, you cannot. But you can create a map<typeinfo*,dynamic_cast_wrapper> allowing you to do what you want. Tell me if you're interested & I'll post a detailed answer.

Comment: That's all right, thanks; I already have a plan for custom RTTI to do this, but wanted to check to see whether I really needed it first.

Comment: I just figured out that my suggestion was partly wrong anyway. It is not easy to properly wrap a dynamic_cast like I suggested !

Comment: Long time ago this was asked .. i am interested if the new C++ standart have some extensions which may cover this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Great thanks to Flexo. I have been researching the C++ ABI for a quite while. After a hour of work, I've got this demo: http://pastebin.com/j7DYY5ej. Here is a code to check inheritance in some cases. I've implemented operators ==, !=, <, >, <=, >= for the types. I'm planning to improve this way of type equation and to use it in my project.
Note that I used G++ 4.8 under Linux.