# "Best fit" dynamic type matching for plugins in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, plugins, reflection

I have an architecture where virtually everything is a plugin. This architecture underlies a graphic user interface where each plugin is represented by a "surface" (i.e. a UI control through which the user can interact with the plugin). These surfaces are also plugins. Whenever a new plugin is added, a thin host automatically determines which of the available surfaces is the best UI match for it. How that dynamic type matching can be accomplished in C++ is the subject of this question.

At present, the architecture is implemented in C#, relying heavily on reflection, as you'll see. However, I am now in the process of redesigning the whole thing for C++, but since C++ doesn't have reflection (and since I am new to C++) I need some input on how to best replicate this functionality without it.

Here's how it's currently done in C# (simplified & pseudo):

All plugins are descendants of a `Plugin` class.

Each surface type is tagged with a 'target plugin type', indicating the most specific / deepest descendant of Plugin it is designed for.

The most generic of the surfaces is one that just handles the level of Plugin (just showing a name label, for example). This guarantees that all plugins will have at least one surface capable of representing them on screen, even if it doesn't provide any useful means of interaction.

Let's call this "baseline" surface type for `PluginSurface`. If - for the sake of brevity here (in reality it's done via Class Attributes) - we use a property on surfaces to indicate their target type, we'd have

```
PluginSurface.TargetType = typeof(Plugin)
```

Unless more specific surfaces are added, all plugins would be assigned this generic surface, no matter where they are in the Plugin inheritance hierarchy.

Now, let's say we add a new plugin type called Father, deriving from Plugin:

```
Father : Plugin
```

Then we add a few more, to create a little sample hierarchy:

```
Mother : Plugin
Daughter : Father
Son1 : Mother
Son2 : Mother
Grandson : Son1
```

At this point, all of these would be represented on screen by the generic `PluginSurface`. So we create additional surfaces to more specifically handle the functionality of the new plugins (all surfaces descend from PluginSurface):

```
MotherSurface.TargetType = typeof(Mother)
GrandsonSurface.TargetType = typeof(Grandson)
```

From this, the effective type matching of plugin-to-surface should be:

```
Father -> PluginSurface
Daughter -> PluginSurface
Mother -> MotherSurface
Son1 -> MotherSurface
Son2 -> MotherSurface
Grandson -> GrandsonSurface
```

Ok, so this is the mapping we expect to end up with. Essentially, the matching is implemented as a static function in the host that takes the plugin type and returns an instance of the best-fit-surface:

```
PluginSurface GetBestFitSurface(Type pluginType)
```

The function iterates through all the available surfaces and checks their `TargetType` property against the supplied `pluginType`. More specifically, it checks whether the TargetType `IsAssignableFrom` the pluginType. It creates a list of all the positive matches.

It then needs to narrow down this list of candidates to *the best fit*. For that I do a similar check of assignability, but this time *between all the candidates' TargetTypes*, checking each one against each of the others, and for each candidate I make a note of how many of the other candidates' TargetTypes its TargetType is assignable to. The candidate whose TargetType can be assigned (i.e. cast) to the most other TargetTypes is the best fit.

What happens later is that this surface becomes a wrapper around the plugin in question, arranging itself on screen to reflect the features of that plugin it "understands", depending of the tightness of the fit. A `GrandsonSurface` is specifically designed to represent `GrandSon`, so it will be a complete UI for that plugin. But `Son1` and `Son2` are "only" getting a `MotherSurface`, so any features they don't have in common with `Mother` will not be included in their UI representation (until a more specialized `Son` interface is made, at which point *that* will be the best fit etc). Note that this the intended use - normally, the Mother plugin would be *abstract* and the interface targeting it would really be a *Son interface*, intended to wrap all of Mother's *children*. Thus a single surface provides the UI for a whole class of similarly featured plugins.

How can this best be done in C++ without the support of reflection?

I suppose the challenge is to smoke out the C++ analog to C#'s `Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)` where both Types are dynamically attributed.. I'm looking in the direction of `dynamic_cast` and `typeid`, but so far I haven't gotten a firm grasp on how to go about it. Any tips on architecture, pattern or implementation details would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 1: I think I have solved the main problem here (see my own answer below, which includes a [very] rough C++ implementation), but there might be better patterns. Feel free to rip it apart.

Edit 2: An improved model is presented in a follow-up question found here: [“Poor Man's Reflection” (AKA bottom-up reflection) in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057938/poor-mans-reflection-in-c).

Comment: Why are you retooling it in C++?

Comment: Long story short - performance, integration with DirectX without marshalling, not wanting the .Net dependency, doing a complete custom layout system anyway etc. It's basically a new software development paradigm / platform upon which others build applications, so I want MY layer to be as close to the metal / light as possible. Plus I like the raw feeling of C++. Reminds me a bit of coding assembler as a kid.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to have a function in your Plugin base class:

```
virtual std::string id() const { return "Plugin"; }
```

Which derived classes can override, for example Grandson knows its base class is Mother, so might code:

```
override std::string id() const { return "Grandson " + Mother::id(); }
```

That way, when you call `id()` on a plugin you get something back like "Grandson Mother Plugin".  You can throw it a `std::stringstream ss(id);`, us a `while (ss >> plugin_id)`, and seek using the `plugin_id` as a key in a container of surfaces....

I don't think you'll find a way to use `typeid` or `dynamic_cast` as flexibly, as `typeid` won't tell you base class (*), and `dynamic_cast` has to know the type it'll test for at compile time.  I assume you want to be able to use new plugins, and change some file or other config of id->surface mappings, without editing your code....

(*) If you're prepared to be non-Standard and it matches you portability requirements, [C++: using typeinfo to test class inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491076/c-using-typeinfo-to-test-class-inheritance) documents a way to get base class `typeinfo` at run time.

Comment: You have understood the dilemma, but I'd prefer not to have to make a "parallel" [string based] inheritance tracking system. Also, I don't want to have any config files etc with mappings - it should happen dynamically and automatically, like it does in C# now. The more self-organizing the system is, the better. But after I asked the question, I had an idea about another approach where I actually _will_ know the type to test for at compile time - which in turn enables me to use `dynamic_cast`.. assuming my thinking is valid. I have put my thoughts in a separate answer to my own question.

Comment: @d7samurai: you may want to check the question I've linked in my last (new) paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it, I realized that the following should work:

Since the surface types are already supposed to be tagged with their respective 'target plugin type', I realized that they might as well have that type *hard coded in them* (as it's not going to change once a surface plugin is compiled. This is basically how the type tagging is done in C# anyway - although there it is done using class Attributes. Duh).

This means that as long as the 'assignability' checking is done *inside each surface class* (that internally knows what type it is targeting) rather than in a global function (that needs to be told both the source and the target type of the check, hence the problem), it becomes a regular cast operation with a known destination type (i.e. the surface's target plugin type).

I guess the relevant function could be templated, so that the template type T would represent their 'target plugin type' and also the known destination type of the cast.

It could have a function like so:

```
bool TargetTypeIsAssignableFrom(Plugin* plugin)
```

and the function would return the result of a regular `dynamic_cast` (i.e. whether such a cast is successful or not):

```
dynamic_cast<T>(plugin)
```

So when the plugin -> surface matching is performed, rather than checking the pluginType against each surface's TargetType in a global function (that would need to be fed both types), *each surface* is simply queried about their compatibility with the plugin in question, which it tests by attempting a dynamic_cast to its *known* T - and the ones that return `true` are considered candidates.

Finally the candidates' TargetTypes are checked against each other to determine the best fit.

Here's a quick and dirty - but functional - illustration of the process (pardon my C++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Plugin {
    protected:
        string _name;
    public:
        Plugin() { _name = "Plugin"; };
        virtual string Name() { return _name; }
};

class Plugin_A : public Plugin {
    public:
        Plugin_A() { _name = "Plugin_A"; };
};

class Plugin_B : public Plugin_A {
    public:
        Plugin_B() { _name = "Plugin_B"; };
};

class Plugin_C : public Plugin {
    public:
        Plugin_C() { _name = "Plugin_C"; };
};

Plugin * Global_Plugin = new Plugin;
Plugin_A * Global_Plugin_A = new Plugin_A;
Plugin_B * Global_Plugin_B = new Plugin_B;

class Surface {
    protected:
        string _name;
    public:
        Surface() { _name = "Surface"; };
        string Name() { return _name; }
        virtual Plugin* TargetType() { return Global_Plugin; }
        virtual bool CanHost(Plugin* plugin) { return dynamic_cast<Plugin*>(plugin) != nullptr; } // TargetType: Plugin
};

class Surface_A : public Surface {
    public:
        Surface_A() { _name = "Surface_A"; };
        Plugin* TargetType() { return Global_Plugin_A; }
        bool CanHost(Plugin* plugin) { return dynamic_cast<Plugin_A*>(plugin) != nullptr; }  // TargetType: Plugin_A
};

class Surface_B : public Surface_A {
    public:
        Surface_B() { _name = "Surface_B"; };
        Plugin* TargetType() { return Global_Plugin_B; }
        bool CanHost(Plugin* plugin) { return dynamic_cast<Plugin_B*>(plugin) != nullptr; }  // TargetType: Plugin_B
};

vector<Surface*> surfaces;

Surface * GetSurface(Plugin* plugin) {
    vector<Surface*> candidates;

    cout << "Candidate surfaces for " << plugin->Name() << ":" << endl;

    for (auto i = begin(surfaces); i != end(surfaces); ++i) {
        if ((*i)->CanHost(plugin)) {
            cout << "\t" << (*i)->Name() << endl;
            candidates.push_back(*i);
        }
    }

    int bestFit = 0, fit;
    Surface * candidate = nullptr;

    for (auto i = begin(candidates); i != end(candidates); ++i) {
        fit = 0;
        for (auto j = begin(candidates); j != end(candidates); ++j) {
            if (j == i || !(*j)->CanHost((*i)->TargetType())) continue;
            ++fit;
        }
        if (candidate != nullptr && fit <= bestFit) continue;
        bestFit = fit;
        candidate = *i;
    }

    cout << "Best fit for " << plugin->Name() << ":" << endl;
    cout << "\t" << candidate->Name() << endl;

    return candidate;
}

int main() {
    Surface * s[3];
    s[0] = new Surface;
    s[1] = new Surface_A;
    s[2] = new Surface_B;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        surfaces.push_back(s[i]);
    }

    Plugin * p[3];
    p[0] = new Plugin_A;
    p[1] = new Plugin_B;
    p[2] = new Plugin_C;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        GetSurface(p[i]);
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        delete p[i];
        delete s[i];
    }

    cin.get();

    delete Global_Plugin;
    delete Global_Plugin_A;
    delete Global_Plugin_B;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: So a surface can't support multiple plugins unless they're related in the plugins class hierarchy, nor target a newly written plugin unless recompiled?  Interesting.  Then `dynamic_cast<>` will work as you hope, and for the best candidate test - you can just have the surfaces code `typedef T Plugin_Target;` then use `std::is_base_of<SurfaceX::Plugin_Target, SurfaceY::Plugin_Target>` to see if `SurfaceY` is a better fit than (i.e. is derived from) `SurfaceX`.

Comment: Each surface is designed for a particular class of plugin in the hierarchy, but it supports all plugins derived from that class. And they can target all subsequent plugins deriving from the same class without being recompiled. In reality, things are somewhat different than the pseudo examples I gave. For example, there would perhaps be an _abstract_ `Mother` plugin and a whole family of derived child plugins (a range of filters, for example). There would be one surface with the Mother as its TargetType, but intended to wrap and dynamically adapt to the features of all the children.

Comment: sure - if that's working well with your actual and planned plugins and surfaces, all's good :-).

Comment: is_base_of<> is no good.. it's a compile-time check - I have to specify the Types explicitly. I need dynamic runtime checking..

Comment: The updated code snippet in my answer above basically works as I want - the main thing missing is the ability to have a surface's TargetType be an _abstract_ class (since that solution is based on comparing pointers to instantiated objects). But I think I can work around that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you come from a language that has reflection and are asking about similar capabilities in C++ and, I suggest you should have a look into "Template Meta Programming" and "Policy based design", "Type traits" and the like and thus pushing these decisions out to compile time, compared to reflection.

In your case, I suggest having a look at tagging the classes appropriately, and making these decisions at compile time using the meta programming techniques offered by  [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same), [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of),
[`std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible), [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional)

As you seem to be moving to a major refactoring, more good, in-depth resources on this topic would be practically everything by [Alexandrescu](https://erdani.org/index.php/articles/), [Alexandrescu's book](http://www.amazon.de/Modern-Generic-Programming-Patterns-Applied/dp/0201704315/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1389172391&sr=8-1&keywords=alexandrescu), [Di Gennaro's book](http://www.amazon.de/Advanced-Metaprogramming-Davide-Di-Gennaro/dp/1460966163/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1389172098&sr=8-1&keywords=di+gennaro+c%2B%2B) and [David Abrahams's book](http://www.amazon.de/Template-Metaprogramming-Concepts-Techniques-In-Depth/dp/0321227255/ref=sr_1_14?ie=UTF8&qid=1389171801&sr=8-14&keywords=c%2B%2B+generic+programming) on these techniques.

I especially found [these](https://web.archive.org/web/20220302134210/http://flamingdangerzone.com/) posts insightful in all these matters to start with...

HTH, since TMP is much fun

Comment: It can't be done at compile time. All the participating modules are dynamically loaded at runtime, so at compile time they don't even know the others exist and thus cannot make use of any information from them until they brush shoulders when the application is started.