# "Poor Man's Reflection" (AKA bottom-up reflection) in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, plugins, reflection, types

I am implementing some rudimentary reflection in C++ for an ultra modular architecture where virtually all features are loaded as plugins and interpreted dynamically at run-time. Since there's a distinct element of structural self-organization to the system, components need some means of inspecting each other (for an example of a situation where this flavor of reflection is needed, see this question: [“Best fit” dynamic type matching for plugins in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988296/best-fit-dynamic-type-matching-for-plugins-in-c)).

The architecture has so far been developed in C#, but I am now looking into how it could be implemented in C++ instead. At this point I have created the skeleton for a "Poor Man's Reflection" based on the following model:

A `Type` class to hold relevant class information:

```
namespace Reflection {

    class Type {
    public:
        Type(Object &, string, bool(*)(Type *));
        ~Type();
        Object & RefObj();
        string Name();
        bool IsAssignableFrom(Type *);
    private:
        Object & _refObj;
        string _name;
        bool(*_isAssignableFrom_Handler)(Type *);
    };

}
```

and an `Object` class from which all participants in the reflection model will descend:

```
class Object {
public:
    Object();
    virtual ~Object();
    virtual string ToString();
    virtual Reflection::Type * GetType();
    static Reflection::Type * Type();
    static bool IsAssignableFrom(Reflection::Type *);
private:
    static Object _refObj;
    static Reflection::Type _type;
};
```

..which is defined like this:

```
string Object::ToString() { return GetType()->Name(); }

// all derived classes must implement the equivalent of this:

Reflection::Type * Object::GetType() { return &_type; }

Object Object::_refObj;

Reflection::Type Object::_type(_refObj, "Object", Object::IsAssignableFrom);

Reflection::Type * Object::Type() { return &_type; }

bool Object::IsAssignableFrom(Reflection::Type * type) {
    return dynamic_cast<Object*>(&type->RefObj()) != nullptr;
}
```

Note that I only need my reflectivity to operate within my own hierarchy of classes (that all inherit from `Object`). The above code therefore now enables me to:

- Get the Type of any instance: `instance.GetType()`
- Get the Type of any class: `class::Type()`
- Compare Types: e.g. `(instance.GetType() == class::Type())` or `(instanceA.GetType() == instanceB.GetType())`
- Perform runtime checks to see if one Type instance can be assigned another (i.e. dynamically, with two "unknowns". All built-in options in C++ seem to require knowing at least one of the Types at compile time), essentially the equivalent of `is` and key to deducing inheritance relationships: `(instanceA.GetType()->IsAssignableFrom(instanceB.GetType()))`
- Reference abstract types dynamically by their Type
- Get a consistent, friendly name of a Type (i.e. class)

This is sufficient for my immediate needs, and the feature range can be extended by adding functionality to the Type class (next up is the ability to instantiate a class just given a Type instance - analog to .Net's `Activator.CreateInstance`). But unlike 'proper' reflection, which is essentially a top-down approach where [meta] information about classes is collected at the compiler level / managed centrally, this is done manually and bottom-up, distributing the knowledge into the objects themselves and giving them a way of communicating it between each other at run-time. So to make this work, every class included in this system needs to implement the same members and functions as the `Object` class, to encapsulate the relevant aspects of themselves for 'export'. Case in point, the `Plugin` class looks like this (definition):

```
Reflection::Type * Plugin::GetType() { return &_type; }

Plugin Plugin::_refObj;

Reflection::Type Plugin::_type(_refObj, "Plugin", Plugin::IsAssignableFrom);

Reflection::Type * Plugin::Type() { return &_type; }

bool Plugin::IsAssignableFrom(Reflection::Type * type) {
    return dynamic_cast<Plugin*>(&type->RefObj()) != nullptr;
}
```

As you can see, it's practically identical to its parent class, `Object`. Almost all of these functions vary only by their class type (and name).

So I have a couple of questions.

- The first one is whether there any methods to streamline this, via compiler macros or clever inheritance / templating etc, since there is / will be so much repetition. It strikes me as something that could be automated? Like extracting out the name of the class (perhaps including namespaces) and just generate the code from that? Or some source code snippet template based on a variable or two (class name coming to mind).
- The second is more general (and the reason I included all this code). I have only been working with C++ for a very short time, so I feel rather n00bish and assume that my approaches and implementation details could be very naive. If there are others that have worked on similar architectures / had similar needs, perhaps they could share their experience (or even just point out flaws in my model / code).

For an example of a situation where this flavor of reflection is needed, see this question: [“Best fit” dynamic type matching for plugins in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988296/best-fit-dynamic-type-matching-for-plugins-in-c).

**Update:**

As far as the first question goes, here is what I ended up doing:

I made two macros, one for the .h file and one for the .cpp file. Now all I need to do is add `REFLECTION_H(TYPE_NAME)` in the class declaration and `REFLECTION_CPP(TYPE_NAME)` in the class definition and all the reflection boiler plate is automatically included. I can then just add class specific members as normal without having to think about reflection, knowing that all the plumbing required is in place and everything just works. For example, with the current implementation, a new `Surface` class would now look like this:

Surface.h:

```
class Surface : public Plugin
{
    REFLECTION_H(Surface)
public:
    // ...class specific public member declarations...
private:
    // ...class specific private member declarations...
};
```

Surface.cpp:

```
REFLECTION_CPP(Surface);

Surface::~Surface() {}

// ...class specific member definitions...
```

The macros are defined like this:

```
#define REFLECTION_H(TYPE_NAME) \
    public:\
    virtual ~TYPE_NAME();\
    static Reflection::Type& Type();\
    private:\
    virtual Reflection::Type& _getType();\
    static TYPE_NAME _refObj;\
    static Reflection::Type _type;\
    static bool IsAssignableFrom(Reflection::Type&);\
    static plugin_ptr CreateInstance();

#define REFLECTION_CPP(TYPE_NAME) \
    Reflection::Type& TYPE_NAME::Type() { return _type; }\
    Reflection::Type& TYPE_NAME::_getType() { return _type; }\
    TYPE_NAME TYPE_NAME::_refObj;\
    Reflection::Type TYPE_NAME::_type(_refObj, #TYPE_NAME, true, IsAssignableFrom, CreateInstance);\
    bool TYPE_NAME::IsAssignableFrom(Reflection::Type& type) { return dynamic_cast<TYPE_NAME*>(&type.RefObj()) != nullptr; }\
    plugin_ptr TYPE_NAME::CreateInstance() { return plugin_ptr(new TYPE_NAME); }
```

Comment: Is this managed C++ ala C++.NET ?

Comment: No, just plain C++ (although I might (deliberately) be using some conventions regarding naming and formatting etc from C# to make myself more comfortable).

Comment: C++ simply wasn't designed to use Reflection (i.e. Run Time Type Information) like C# or Java.

Comment: Well, why don't you use one of the standard "component architectures" available for all major OSes (and minor too) nowadays? Or maybe it's just an exercise to study these advanced techniques? Anyway I would suggest to take a look on existing C++ libraries such as ROOT.Reflex (http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/reflex) or Boost.Reflex http://bytemaster.github.io/boost_reflect/index.html, although the latter seems abandoned.

Comment: @Keeler I know. But as you can see, I need it. Therefore I must implement a certain part of such functionality myself. Hence the question.

Comment: Do you *need* it because you're trying to port this over from a language that *did* have proper reflection, like C#? It's just going to turn into a hideous, unmaintainable, **nightmare** if you throw macros on top of those classes. At least, that's my opinion :)

Comment: @Keeler I am not _porting_ anything. But I am building something that has.. let's just say special needs related to ultra-modularity. I don't need fully fledged reflection, like .Net provides. But I need to be able to do certain things conveniently, as loosely illustrated in the supplied code. I am building a complete framework where all the classes involved are made from scratch anyway, so adding a few members is virtually like getting it for free. The "macros" I'm talking about would just be like a snipped that auto-codes a few lines - like the ones shown for the `Plugin` class.

Comment: ... also if you actually need "a set of macros" to cover all the gory details under the hood, you may take a look a Vala language which, essentially, is an "advanced C pre-processor" implementing all the modern programming languages features, like OOP, introspection and some sort of co-routines etc in plain C (not even C++!) https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ But, huh, it's a way for a true samurai :)

Comment: It could literally be a mechanism allowing me to, say, write "<INSERT BOILERPLATE REFLECTION CODE FOR A CLASS NAMED "Surface" HERE>" - filling in the same code based on a template, replacing %X% for the name or something. It's just for productivity reasons - plus if I change something, I could just change the template, rather than going over all the classes manually..

Comment: Well, I think it could be more convenient to create a proxy class for each entity to be "reflected". With this appoach your "main" code, the code implementing the logic of the module, isn't polluted with the reflection boilerplate. You may take a look at code-analyzing/code mastering projects such as [GCC XML](http://gccxml.github.io/HTML/Index.html) which builds a XML description of a given C++ code. You may use, for example, a XSL-transformation to create a proxy C++ class from a generated XML description of your class

Comment: @d7samurai What do you know, that's exactly what I gave you! :)

Comment: nobody has suggested crtp?  I am seeing nothing that would be difficult with that.

Comment: I have a tiny program that extracts classes and enums: https://github.com/hun-nemethpeter/cpp-reflector-mini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Python**

Since you mentioned you're in VisualStudio, the macros I wrote below may not work for you (in my experience, macros can be obnoxious cross-platform). So, here's a Python sample that you can run as a pre-build script generate the *.cpp files based on the names in a text file.

**create_classes.py**

```py
template = """Reflection::Type * {0}::GetType() {{
    return &_type;
}}

// static type info

{0} {0}::_refObj;

Reflection::Type {0}::_type(_refObj, "{0}", {0}::IsAssignableFrom);

Reflection::Type * {0}::Type() {{
    return &_type;
}}

bool {0}::IsAssignableFrom(Reflection::Type * type) {{
    return dynamic_cast<{0}*>(&type->RefObj()) != nullptr;
}}
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('classes', 'r') as classes:
        for class_name in classes:
            class_name = class_name.strip()
            with open('{0}.cpp'.format(class_name), 'w') as source:
                source.write(template.format(class_name))
```

**classes** (text file)

```
Blossom
Bubbles
Buttercup
```

Which will create Blossom.cpp, Bubbles.cpp, and Buttercup.cpp using the template above. Getting the correct names into the 'classes' text file is up to you. :)

I'm sure you can adapt this to split each definition across *.hpp and *.cpp, let me know if this is helpful.

## **C++ Macros**

As much as I dislike macros (and I still advise against using them when possible!) here are macros that will generate your code. I haven't tested them thoroughly, so they could shoot you in the foot. They're also named poorly (unclear what the macros do from their names), but this is the idea.

**macros.cpp**

```
#define GET_TYPE_METHOD(X) \
    Reflection::Type * X::GetType() { return &_type; }

#define GET_REF_OBJ(X) X X::_refObj;

#define GET_UNDERSCORE_TYPE(X) \
    Reflection::Type X::_type(_refObj, #X, X::IsAssignableFrom);

#define GET_TYPE(X) \
    Reflection::Type * X::Type() { return &_type; }

#define GET_IS_ASSIGNABLE_FROM(X) \
    bool X::IsAssignableFrom(Reflection::Type * type) { return dynamic_cast<X*>(&type->RefObj()) != nullptr; }

GET_TYPE_METHOD(Keeler)
GET_REF_OBJ(Keeler)
GET_UNDERSCORE_TYPE(Keeler)
GET_TYPE(Keeler)
GET_IS_ASSIGNABLE_FROM(Keeler)
```

If you run `g++ -E macros.cpp`, you get the preprocessor output. Check out what the preprocessor thinks:

```
$ g++ -E macros.cpp
# 1 "macros.cpp"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "macros.cpp"
# 16 "macros.cpp"
Reflection::Type * Keeler::GetType() { return &_type; }
Keeler Keeler::_refObj;
Reflection::Type Keeler::_type(_refObj, "Keeler", Keeler::IsAssignableFrom);
Reflection::Type * Keeler::Type() { return &_type; }
bool Keeler::IsAssignableFrom(Reflection::Type * type) { return dynamic_cast<Keeler*>(&type->RefObj()) != nullptr; }
```

Is this along the lines of what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, this looks promising :) I am using Visual Studio, if that makes a difference. I see that here, you have essentially made a macro for each of the function / member definitions. I assume that those could be made into one single macro that defines them all (that is, one for the .h and one for the .cpp).

Comment: Not tested with VisualStudio, sorry. Editing to provide a solution in Python.

Comment: @d7samurai I wouldn't trust those macros in VisualStudio (just to be safe), so I added a Python script that creates the classes for you. You can use this as a pre-build script. As for splitting across .hpp and .cpp files, you can adapt the python script to your liking.

Comment: I accepted your answer since I ended up using it as a reference point for building my macros. See the question update for my final implementation.

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help a bit. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

Just to summarize:

1. there's a lot of existing industry-standard frameworks to implement loadable modules in C++, with different levels of module introspection. Just to name a few: MSWindows COM and variants, CORBA (various implementations), KDE KParts, DBus-enabled services on Linux and other Unix-like OSes etc. In general I would go with one of existing variant depending on target platform and other considerations
2. If you absolutely need to costruct your own bike^W framework, I would separate classes implementing module business-logic from the boilerplate. Certainly this approach introduces another level of indirection and this may cause some performance issues. But if done clever this boilerplate may be quite thin, almost unperceivable. Also separating BL from the framework would allow to completely change the horse w/o much efforts in future. To go with this approach I would choose code manipulating tools like [GCC-XML](http://gccxml.github.io/HTML/Index.html) or appropriate CLang modules.
3. Also there're a number of existing C++ libraries from simple to complex to build your own tightly composed framework. Examples: [ROOT Reflex](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/reflex), [Boost.Reflect](http://bytemaster.github.io/boost_reflect/index.html)

The rest is under your own choice. I know that people of Gnome project, unsatisfied with deficiencies and shortcomings of C++, invented their own OOP framework on plain C (GLib/GObject) and later developed on that basis a new fully functional language similar to C# ([Vala](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/)). It's all up to you where to stop yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.. Also look through: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define __FUNC_NAME__ __FUNCTION__
#else
#define __FUNC_NAME__ __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
#endif // _MS_VER

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define RF_DETAIL  std::string GetDetail() {return __FUNCSIG__;}
#else
#define RF_DETAIL  std::string GetDetail() {return __FUNC_NAME__;}
#endif


#define RF_CLASS   std::string GetClass() {\
                         const std::string name = __FUNC_NAME__;\
                         std::string::size_type beg = name.find_first_of(" "), end = name.find_first_of("<");\
                         if (!end) end = name.find_first_of("::");\
                         return name.substr(beg + 1, end - beg - 1); }

#define RF_TYPE    auto GetType() -> std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type {return std::move(std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type()); }

#define RF_TYPE_PTR    auto GetTypePtr() -> decltype(this) {return this;}

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
    public:
        RF_DETAIL;
        RF_CLASS;
        RF_TYPE;
        virtual ~Foo(){}
};

template<typename T>
class Meh : public Foo<T>
{
    public:
        RF_DETAIL;
        RF_CLASS;
        RF_TYPE;
        virtual ~Meh(){}
};

class Go
{
    public:
        RF_DETAIL;
        RF_CLASS;
        RF_TYPE;
        RF_TYPE_PTR;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> f;
    std::cout<<f.GetDetail()<<"\n\n";
    std::cout<<f.GetClass()<<"\n\n\n";

    Meh<int> g;
    std::cout<<g.GetDetail()<<"\n\n";
    std::cout<<g.GetClass()<<"\n";


    Goo h;
    decltype(h.GetType()) i;
    std::cout<<i.GetClass();
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
std::string Foo<T>::GetDetail() [with T = int; std::string = std::basic_string<c
har>]

Foo


std::string Meh<T>::GetDetail() [with T = int; std::string = std::basic_string<c
har>]

Meh


Foo::GetClass()
```